# How to get a row number column in SAS EG to ease the selection of rows by that unique number?? I want to use PROC SQL syntax

Tags: sql, sas, enterprise-guide

I want to create a column called rowno that is basically like a serial number  to my existing table, so the deletion or selection of rows is easy even with duplicate values.
 INPUT:

```
Name Date   Count
BAC  10/12  45
GBS  10/12  54
JDJA 10/13  89
SAK  10/13  11
YHN  10/14  76
JUK  10/14  76
```

OUPUT:

```
Name Date   Count **ROWno**.
BAC  10/12  45     1
GBS  10/12  54     2
JDJA 10/13  89     3
SAK  10/13  11     4
YHN  10/14  76     5
JUK  10/14  09     6
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use *n* operator in datastep.

Let’s say your input dataset is INPUT, use below data step to create a new dataset Output with column rownum

```
Data Output;
Set Input;
rownum = _n_;
run;
```

This code will work on any of the Sas box, sas eg, Sas studio etc.

Answer (score 0):

monotonic() is an undocumented function which does what you want.

```
data have;
input Name $ Date $   Count;
datalines;
BAC  10/12  45
GBS  10/12  54
JDJA 10/13  89
SAK  10/13  11
YHN  10/14  76
JUK  10/14  76
;

proc sql noprint;
create table want as
select *,monotonic() as rowno from have;quit;
```